# Drupal 7 webform module is not sending email properly

Tags: email, drupal-7, drupal-webform

I have this modules enabled in my drupal 7 site:

- Mail System
- Mime Mail
- Smtp Authentication

I have configured Mail system to "format" mails with MIME Mail and "mail" with SMTP Authentication. This configuration is set as site-wide default class.

It works fine for register user email, but when send mail with webforms it doesn't use that configuration (It sends emails with a local smtp).

How can I make webform take mail system configuration?

Comment: Here is what I found facing this problem. It should help :)
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77608/drupal-7-webform-module-is-not-sending-email-properly#answer-77852